# transparent png iOS Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, png, popover

I am trying to have a transparent png display as a popover. I have tried adding the image to a view controller and setting the background color to `UIColor.clearcolor()`. However, I am not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the alpha of the view to something between 0 and 1?

Comment: any ideas on how i can center the view vs having it in the upper right corner?

Comment: Yeah you should use auto layout constraints.  If you're new to Xcode, this is definitely something worth learning.  If you place an image view on the view controller in storyboard. You can ctrl drag from the image view to the main view and set constraints the determine the size and position of the image view, on of which is to center horizontally.  Also, could you accept my answer :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `UIPopoverController` ? Have you tried changing the `backgroundColor` property of your `UIPopoverController` instance?